# remove multiple line from /etc/hosts using augtool

Tags: bash, puppet, augeas

My /etc/hosts look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.13.11   idm.myhost.com
192.168.13.10   dnsf.myhost.com
192.168.13.11   idm.myhost.com
192.168.13.10   dnsf.myhost.com
192.168.13.11   idm.myhost.com
192.168.13.10   dnsf.myhost.com
192.168.13.10   temp1.myhost.com
```

I can query duplicated lines by query below:

```
 print /files/etc/hosts/*/canonical["idm.myhost.com"]
```

or either use regex

```
defvar mypath /files/etc/hosts
print $mypath/*/*[.=~ regexp("dnsf.myhost.com")]
```

But I can't remove these matched lines with a simple rm

```
rm /files/etc/hosts/*/canonical["idm.myhost.com"]
```

The problem is, augtool just removes the canonical leaf from the node and ipaddr remains. it cause the save function to returns error.
I don't want to use bash script and I try to solve the problem with augeas itself.
Assist, please...

P.S. I couldn't find a complete tutorial or document for this useful tool. I would be thankful is someone can propose a good document. I've searched all the web and just found a few simple examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression selects the canonical node instead of the host node. If you want to delete the host nodes, you need to use:

```
rm /files/etc/hosts/*[canonical="idm.myhost.com"]
```

This selects any entry under `/files/etc/hosts`, *whose* `canonical` subnode has value `idm.myhost.com`.

As for documentation, there's a tutorial [on the Augeas website](https://augeas.net/tour.html), as well as some more docs on [the Augeas wiki](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/wiki).

There's also a video intro to Augeas [on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufRzrXNKgoo).

I started [writing a book](https://github.com/raphink/Augeas-book) some 7 years ago, which can [still be found online](http://r.pinson.free.fr/augeas/augeas-book.pdf), but never tpok the time to finish it.

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks.
I hope you can find time to finish your handy book. Anyway, I'm starting to read it.